# My code prints none when trying to webscrape

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm a beginner just started learning python a week ago, I was trying to get a product title for a specific product on amazon but when I try to run my code it prints "None" instead of printing the title, Any help?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Sony-ILCE7SM2-mount-Camera-Full-Frame/dp/B0158SRJVQ/ref=sr_1_1?        
dchild=1&keywords=a7s&qid=1589917834&sr=8-1'
headers = {
    'user_agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id='productTitle')

print(title)
```

Comment: What does `print(page.content)` show? It's possible the page your request is getting back from the server is not the same as the page you're seeing in a typical browser.

Comment: Amazon recognises such automated requests. You'd probably be getting an error saying something like, `To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.`